# AWS Elastic Beanstalk additional ssl Load Balancer not saving

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk application that I"m trying to add https/ssl to. I added a listener, selected port 443 and https, selected my certificate, and then hit save.

I scroll down to the bottom of the page and make sure I hit apply, the server then rebuilds... but when I go back to look the https listener is gone!!

I never get an errors or anything weird, any ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. I believe it was an incompatible SSL security policy switching to ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08 fixed it. Found the answer here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html